# Integrate Moodle player to play Scorm File in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, moodle, scorm

Everyone I needed help regarding integration of Moodle player in my Laravel site to play scorm files.

I have a scorm file in my Laravel site and when user click on any lesson then it use Moodle player.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a scorm activity in a course, then upload the file as a package.

Go to the course in Moodle, turn editing on, then click the add an activity button, then select Scorm.

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Activities

Comment: Russell England i am new to moodle can u guide me in a detail if u don't mind please..

Comment: local means that i don't want to use moodle table i use my database table i only integrate the moodle player to my application database